# Error in a copied code

Tags: java, android

I'm looking in a article regarding a `listviews` and `buttons`. Now I have copied the code that he wrote. But unfortunetaly I get an error.

I have a `activity_main`, `Child_listview`, `ListAdapter.java` and `MainActivity.java.`
In the last one I'm getting a error.I have put the errors in Bold lettering.

Error 1 says: `ListAdapter is abstract`; cannot be instantiated

Error 2 says: Cannot resolve method. I'm guessing this because it is looking for the method in the wrong javafile. It is looking for it in `MainAcitivity` instead of `ListAdapter`.

```
private ListView listView;
ListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> dataItems = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] dataArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listdata);
    List<String> dataTemp = Arrays.asList(dataArray);
    dataItems.addAll(dataTemp);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = **new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, dataItems)**;
    adapter.**setCustomButtonListner**(MainActivity.this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you give us the link of your source ?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9e8439/create-custom-listener-on-button-in-listitem-listview-in-a/

Comment: you should put your logcat instead of just telling the error

Comment: Keep reading.... **he creates the ListAdapter** !!!

Comment: @Nomad, there is no Logcat since he doesn't compile is program,

Comment: @JeroenvanderSchalie Did you check if you use the correct ListAdapter in imports (com.example.articalonlistiner.ListAdapter) or some other ListAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

If you keep scrolling on this article, you will find out that he create this ListAdapter (which is a terrible name for a Custom adapter)

Here is the code of his class

```
package com.example.articalonlistiner;   

import java.util.ArrayList;   

import android.content.Context;   
import android.view.LayoutInflater;   
import android.view.View;   
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;   
import android.view.ViewGroup;   
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;   
import android.widget.Button;   
import android.widget.TextView;   

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {   
    customButtonListener customListner;   

    public interface customButtonListener {   
        public void onButtonClickListner(int position,String value);   
    }   

    public void setCustomButtonListner(customButtonListener listener) {   
        this.customListner = listener;   
    }   

    private Context context;   
    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();   

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> dataItem) {   
        super(context, R.layout.child_listview, dataItem);   
        this.data = dataItem;   
        this.context = context;   
    }   

    @Override   
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
        ViewHolder viewHolder;   
        if (convertView == null) {   
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);   
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_listview, null);   
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();   
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView   
                    .findViewById(R.id.childTextView);   
            viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView   
                    .findViewById(R.id.childButton);   
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);   
        } else {   
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();   
        }   
        final String temp = getItem(position);   
        viewHolder.text.setText(temp);   
        viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   

            @Override   
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                if (customListner != null) {   
                    customListner.onButtonClickListner(position,temp);   
                }   

            }   
        });   

        return convertView;   
    }   

    public class ViewHolder {   
        TextView text;   
        Button button;   
    }   
}
```

This is clearly a lack of attention on your part. You can't copy a piece of code and hope that it will work if you don't read everything.

EDIT (from the comments below) :

This is also important to make sur that you use the correct ListAdapter. You need to import the custom `ListAdapter` and not the one from the Android widget package.

Comment: This clearly shows that you didn't read my note above the code. Where I already wrote that I do have the ListAdapter.java but still had the errors. I do want to thank you for your input.

Comment: Since the ListAdapter is clearly not abstract, either this is not the same file or you simply have imported the ListAdapter interface from `android.widget.ListAdapter`. Remove the ListAdapter imports to use the correct ListAdapter (Custom made). Specify the package if it is different thant the activity. EDIT : So yes, I did read your question but the file name don't tell me the content.

Comment: Haha I understand it now. And I really appreciate your effort to help. I'm at the start of learning java and android, so I have long way to go. I removed it and indeed it works now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't worry about Android, This is basicly a big library, if you understand Java, you will understand Android. Fell free to accept this answer, I have edited it to contains the import part.